# Check if a rule already exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When creating a rule for a user defined data type, how do I check if the rule already exists?

```
-- does rule exist?
CREATE RULE MyRule
AS @MyVar IN ('foo1', 'foo2')
```

Comment: As an aside, rules are deprecated and will eventually be removed of SQL Server. You should use check constraints instead

Comment: How about checking exists in sys.objects tables?

Comment: @Lamak: Are u sure that I can use constraints for user defined types/table types? Look here: 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58348/user-defined-table-type-with-a-check-constraint

Comment: @Schwammkopf I don't really understand your question, but yes, check constraints can (I mean, whay else would the exist?) be used in user defined tables. The link you posted just shows wrong syntax being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if not  exists(Select 1 from sys.all_objects where type='r')
begin

create rule syntax

end
```

You could also use sys.objects

```
 if not  exists(Select 1 from sys.objects where type='r')
    begin

    create rule syntax

    end
```

**References:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-all-objects-transact-sql